# Arduino Yun - Sensor Data logging to MYSQL on External Server

Tags: arduino-yun

I want to log data from Sensors (Say Temperature, moisture or humidity) to a MYSQL database (provided by a online hosting company). Is it possible to establish communication between Arduino Yun and that database and log the data to it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that [using python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-examples.html) as well as other languages, or you can [use Temboo](https://www.temboo.com/arduino/yun/mysql): there's an example bundled with the Arduino IDE, it's called "SendDataToMySQL"